# How to save entity Many-to-Many With a New Entity with with extra columns in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to save entity Student with Course entity, but I have an extra Entity class StudentCourse to put starting date of the course and ending date.
How to persist all data at once?
This is my code until now:

```
@Entity
public class Student{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses;

//have getter and setters and overridden hashCode() and equals
}
```

```
@Entity
public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    Course course;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses;

}
```

I need to save entity student with Set of courses, also I need to add the start date and end date into the StudentCourse table. I m using the JpaRepository interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `cascade` to `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class Student{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses;

//have getter and setters and overridden hashCode() and equals
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    Student student;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    Course course;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

This defines the set of cascadable operations that are propagated to the associated entity. The value `cascade = ALL` is equivalent to `cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH }`. Additional details  [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types).

Now with a Repository you can save `Student`:

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

Once you have an instance of `StudentRepository` you can call `studentRepository.save(student)` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need a service method to save all this at once. Any example would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use `cascade` in the `@OneToMany` annotations in your case. I suggest not to use it and follow these steps to persist them.

1. Persist the `Student` and `Course` instance respectively.(I suggest use `ManyToOne` in the joint entity only).
2. Set up the relation between `Student` and `Course` in a new `StudentCourse`(maybe use the name `CourseRegistration` is better) instance and persist it. **NOTE, the student and course instance should be the persisted instance in the first step**.

You can wrap the above steps in a transaction scope.

```java
// dummy codes.
@Service 
@Transactional
class SomeService {

    public void saveCourseWithStudents(){
      var savedCourse = courseRepository.save(course);
      var savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);
    
      studentCourse.setCourse(savedCourse );
      studentCourse.setStudent(savedStudent );

      studentCourseRepsoitory.save(studentCourse);
    }

}
```

I have [an existing Spring Boot example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/rest-many-to-many) (including detailed testing codes, and Github actions for continuous testing, dockerizing etc.) demos how to design Restful APIs in a many to many relation, which is very similar to your case, but I used `@ManyToMany` annotation directly.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a good solution to my problem.